# How to find available batches inside of number range in php

Tags: php, recursion

There is a problem that I'm spending some time to figure out a solution.

There is a main number batch. For example 100 - 150(size - 51).
And also there are few sub batches inside of that main batch. For example 105 - 110 and 120 - 130.

I want to get other batches and their batch sizes inside of main batch. 
For example 
 100-104, 111-119 and 131-150

I have tried to find a solution for this but haven't found any solution yet. Is there anyone who can guide me to do this in php or give pseudocode, it will be very helpful for me.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps if you gave some real examples with some real PHP datastructures it would be easier for us to work out what you mean

Comment: Please provide what you've come up to or how the code should present(made up code). We are nor free workers, remember. ;)

Comment: Actually I want some guide to resolve this issue. Actually I don't have any idea to implement this.

Comment: @cha You really don't need a recusing for that. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `array_diff`, you can find the free spaces in your array of batches.

Then extract from this list the parts without interruption of keys, resulting in each free ranges left.

```
$mainBatch = range(100, 150);

$subBatch = range(110, 120);
$subBatch2 = range(130,145);

$subBatchesFree = array_diff($mainBatch, $subBatch, $subBatch2);

$remainingBatches = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($subBatchesFree as $key => $available) {
    if (isset($subBatchesFree[$key + 1])) {
        // Next key is still in the range
        ++$i;
    } else { 
        // Next key is in a new range. 
        // I create the current one and init for the next range
        $remainingBatches[] = range($subBatchesFree[$key - $i], $available);
        $i = 0;
    }
}

print_r($remainingBatches);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 101
            [2] => 102
            [3] => 103
            [4] => 104
            [5] => 105
            [6] => 106
            [7] => 107
            [8] => 108
            [9] => 109
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 121
            [1] => 122
            [2] => 123
            [3] => 124
            [4] => 125
            [5] => 126
            [6] => 127
            [7] => 128
            [8] => 129
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 146
            [1] => 147
            [2] => 148
            [3] => 149
            [4] => 150
        )

)
```

Comment: Is there anyway to create dynamic subBath arrays and pass as arguments?

Comment: @Cha You mean in `array_diff` ?

Comment: Yes. I can create arrays of subBatches. But those are dynamic arrays. Therefore I try to find a way to pass them as arguments to array_diff. I found a solution just now. call_user_func_array('array_diff', $this->array_of_arrays); Is this correct way to do this?

Comment: @cha Yes, it's a good way. Mind that your `$mainBatch` array has to be the very first array of your array_of_arrays.